# Does voting on review posts affect my homepage?

Tags: discussion, review

I'm inclined to give out upvotes to newbies who are writing clear responses on https://stackoverflow.com/review/

But, if voting on questions potentially affect things on my homepage, that's a negative unwanted side effect of this behavior, since the things on my review page aren't correlated to my interests.

Does this happen? Can it be adjusted to not happen like that?

Comment: What do you mean with "my homepage"?

Comment: @kiam: the [new homepage](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) determines what to show you based on a number of inputs... The question is if voting is included in that determination.

Comment: I think this is a positive inclination, +1 for asking the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, we do not look at voting patterns when determining how to filter the "interesting" tab for the front page on Stack Overflow.